# Eigenvector centrality written as infinite sum

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is the formula for Bonacich (aka. eigenvector) centrality. 
$c(\alpha, \beta) = \alpha(I-\beta R)^{-1}R1$ where I is the identity matrix and $1$ is a column of ones.

I've seen the following argument in a few articles with no explanantion: 
"When $\beta$ is less in absolute value than the reciprocal of the largest eigenvalue of R, $c(\alpha,\beta)$ can be written as an infinite sum
$$c(\alpha,\beta) = \alpha \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\beta^k R^{k+1}1 = 
\alpha (R1 + \beta R^2 1 + \beta^2 R^3 1+\ldots  $$ "

Can anyone explain how or why this holds? I am just looking for something high level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at $(I-\beta R)^{-1}$, if $\beta$ is smaller than the eigenvalue, then the inverse should exist, and so it can be safely expressed by the geometric series expansion.  $(I-\beta R)^{-1} = 1+\beta R + (\beta R)^2 +...$

Multiplying on the rest of the terms gives you your answer.

Comment: That was so easy cannot believe I missed that!